# Prove that the sequence converges to zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$a_n=\sqrt{n+3} - \sqrt n$$

Can someone please give me a detailed way of how to prove that this sequence converges to zero?

Comment: You haven't even taken a look at tour page!

Answer (score 7):

HINT:

$$\sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt n=\frac{n+3-n}{\sqrt{n+3}+\sqrt n}=\frac3{\sqrt{n+3}+\sqrt n}$$

Comment: Yes thanks for this but doesn't the proof have to start with a given epsilon which is more than zero? Confused :/

Comment: @daren: You are right. So this is a hint not an actual answer. You may try to formulate the proof using the hint.

Comment: Can you explain how, step by step?

Comment: @daren No. That is not the purpose of this page. The purpose is to *help* you solve the problems you have. Not solve them for you.

Comment: I am already aware of this hint but do not know what to do after this.

Comment: @daren, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n+3}+\sqrt n)=?$$

Comment: @daren You *work* after this. You take a look at what you did in class, and try to do something similar. You *think* about the problem. That is the only way to learn mathematics.

Comment: I have looked through my notes from class but we have not done a similar example to this. Please help

Comment: @daren Calculate and check. $\sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt n=\frac{\sqrt{n+3}+\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n+3}+\sqrt n}\cdot \sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt n= \ldots = \frac3{\sqrt{n+3}+\sqrt n}$

Comment: I know this but don't you have to simplify this further? Also, what N do you choose and how do you show that N is less than epsilon?

Comment: You should use the fact that the function $f(n)=\sqrt{n+3}+\sqrt{n}$ is a monotonically increasing function......so at $lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)=\infty$.